# Boxplots for Likert scale survey results with long group labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data has 5 observations for each statement that the respondent was asked to answer and then the variables 1-5 by respondent ID.

I managed to do a `boxplot` using base R, but my labels are way too long (5-8 words) and I can't seem to make it work with the par function.

```
q4 <- par(mar=c(8, 2, 1, 1))
q4 <- boxplot(np$ab_overused_nationally4, np$ab_overused_work4, 
              np$ab_amr_problem4, np$ab_amr_problem_work4,
              np$ab_better_use4, ylab="Likert Scale", las=2, names=question4,
              main="How much do you agree with the following statements", 
              col=(c("gold", "darkgreen")))
```

So I figured I'd try `ggplot` as it seems to have a bit more flexibility, but I cannot figure out how to do this with only one axis. I also saw some really neat stacked bars to visualize the data, but again, I don't even know where to start.

Edit to add the df:

```
# A tibble: 19 x 5
   ab_overused_nationally4 ab_overused_work4 ab_amr_problem4 ab_amr_problem_work4 ab_better_use4
                     <dbl>             <dbl>           <dbl>                <dbl>          <dbl>
 1                       4                 2               4                    4              5
 2                       4                 4               4                    3              4
 3                       5                 3               4                    2              5
 4                       3                 3               4                    2              5
 5                       5                 3               5                    4              5
 6                       5                 4               5                    5              5
 7                       4                 1               5                    2              5
 8                       5                 1               4                    2              5
 9                       4                 2               4                    3              5
```

Comment: Could you dput your data please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the strings at a width of around say `15` using `strwrap` and `paste`'em together with a linebreak `\n` in the same step.

```
txt <- lapply(question4, function(x) paste(strwrap(x, width=15), collapse="\n"))
```

Then set `xaxt="n"` and use `axis` and `mtext` to build your own.

```
op <- par(mai=c(1.2, 1, 1, 1))  ## set par and store defaults
boxplot(np, xaxt="n", main="foo", col=c(3, 7))
axis(1, at=axTicks(1), labels=FALSE)  ## produces ticks
mtext(txt, 1, 4, at=axTicks(1), cex=.7)  ## produces labels
par(op)  ## restore par defaults
```

[image]

For the sake of flexibility, I would recommend sticking with base graphics. No need to bother with `ggplot2`.

---

*Data:*

```
np <- structure(list(ab_overused_nationally4 = c(4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 4L), ab_overused_work4 = c(2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), ab_amr_problem4 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
4L, 4L), ab_amr_problem_work4 = c(4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 
2L, 3L), ab_better_use4 = c(5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9"))

question4 <- rep("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr?", 5)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you so much! Just one question, can you explain which part of the code creates the number of ticks? I have a few more Likert questions to create Boxplots for and it always gives me 4 with this code and I cannot follow where/how that is happening. Thanks

Comment: @Petra Of course! It's the `axTicks(side=1)` I've used which depends on the `boxplot` you've created just before. It's quite handy but you could also manually do `at=1:5` or whatever the number of your boxes is.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

np %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Hmm maybe. It looks promising, but it doesn't give me an proper box plot, just a shorter or longer line as data points